# Nested case statements vs multiple criteria case statements

Tags: sql-server, optimization

Had an interesting discussion with a colleague today over optimizing case statements and whether it's better to leave a case statement which has overlapping criteria as individual when clauses, or make a nested case statement for each of the overlapping statements.

As an example, say we had a table with 2 integer fields, column a and column b. Which of the two queries would be more processor friendly? Since we're only evaluating if a=1 or a=0 once using the nested statements, would this be more efficient for the processor, or would creating a nested statement eat up that optimization?

Multiple criteria for the case statement:

```
Select 
case 
    when a=1 and b=0 THEN 'True'
    when a=1 and b=1 then 'Trueish'
    when a=0 and b=0 then 'False'
    when a=0 and b=1 then 'Falseish'
    else null
end AS Result
FROM tableName
```

Nesting case statements:

```
Select
case
    when a=1 then
        case 
            when b=0 then 'True'
            when b=1 then 'Trueish'
        end
    When a=0 then
        case
            when b=0 then 'False'
            when b=1 then 'Falseish'
        end
    else null
end AS Result
FROM tablename
```

Comment: If this really is the structure of your problem (with two independent variables) then you could just do: `case when a=1 then 'True' when a=0 then 'False' end || case when b=0 then '' when b=1 then 'ish' end as Result`, right?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Someone may come along and dig into the details of how these operations are actually processed on the CPUs, or what instructions get generated differently between those two queries.  **But from a practical standpoint, it seems that there's not a significant difference.**

This loads up a table with 10 million rows of two bit columns, with a somewhat arbitrary distribution of 1 and 0 values.

```
CREATE DATABASE [239583];
GO

USE [239583];
GO

SELECT TOP 10000000
    CASE WHEN v.number % 2 = 0 THEN CAST(1 AS bit) ELSE CAST(0 AS bit) END AS a,
    CASE WHEN v.number % 2 = 1 THEN CAST(1 AS bit) ELSE CAST(0 AS bit) END AS b
INTO dbo.TableName
FROM master.dbo.spt_values v
    CROSS JOIN master.dbo.spt_values v2
    CROSS JOIN master.dbo.spt_values v3;
```

I then told SSMS to discard results after execution (Query -> Query Options -> Grid -> Discard results after execution), because I don't have time to wait on SSMS to crash loading 20mm rows of 1s and 0s.

Then ran this code:

```
SET STATISTICS IO, TIME ON;

Select 
case 
    when a=1 and b=0 THEN 'True'
    when a=1 and b=1 then 'Trueish'
    when a=0 and b=0 then 'False'
    when a=0 and b=1 then 'Falseish'
    else null
end
FROM tableName;

Select 
case
    when a=1 then
        case 
            when b=0 then 'True'
            when b=1 then 'Trueish'
        end
    When a=0 then
        case
            when b=0 then 'False'
            when b=1 then 'Falseish'
        end
    else null
end
FROM tablename;
```

I typical run has CPU output like this on my machine:

```
Query 1: CPU time = 2141 ms,  elapsed time = 2191 ms.
Query 2: CPU time = 2359 ms,  elapsed time = 2461 ms.
```

Sometimes they are slightly closer to equal, or the second query is slightly faster, but I think those are just the usual variations of the CPUs on my laptop doing other stuff than just running this query.