# CASE WHEN with Multiple conditions

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create new column using following conditions in MySQL Workbench. I followed this example [Nested case statements vs multiple criteria case statements](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/239583/nested-case-statements-vs-multiple-criteria-case-statements) and i am able to get all the results except after ELSE command.

```
 CREATE TABLE Test (
                ID INT NOT NULL,
                Asian CHAR(7),
                Black CHAR(9),
                White CHAR(6),
                Hispanic CHAR(5),
                Pacific CHAR(7),
                Middle CHAR(9),
                Other CHAR(6)
                );
 
insert into Test values 
(1,'Yes','No','No','No', 'Yes','No','No'),
(2,'No','Yes','No','No', 'No','No','No'),
(3,'No','No','Yes','No', 'No','No','No'),
(4,'No','No','No','Yes', 'No','No','No'),
(5,'No','No','No','No', 'Yes','No','No'),
(6,'No','No','No','No', 'No','Yes','No'),
(7,'No','No','No','No', 'No','No','Yes'),
(8,'No','No','No','No', 'Yes','No','Yes'),
(9,'No','Yes','No','No', 'No','No','Yes'),
(10,'Yes','Yes','Yes','No', 'No','No','Yes'),
(11,'No','No','Yes','Yes', 'No','No','Yes'),
(12,'No','No','No','Yes', 'No','No','Yes'),
(13,'No','Yes','No','No', 'No','No','Yes')
;

Select ID, Asian, Black, White, Hispanic, Pacific, Middle, Other,
case
when Asian='Yes' then
    case 
        when Black='No' then 'Asian'
        when White='No' then 'Asian'
        when Hispanic='No' then 'Asian'
        when Pacific='No' then 'Asian'
        when Middle='No' then 'Asian'
        when Other='No' then 'Asian'
    end
When Black='Yes' then
    case
        when Asian='No' then 'Black'
        when White='No' then 'Black'
        when Hispanic='No' then 'Black'
        when Pacific='No' then 'Black'
        when Middle='No' then 'Black'
        when Other='Yes' then 'Black'
    end
When White='Yes' then
    case
        when Asian='No' then 'White'
        when Black='No' then 'White'
        when Hispanic='No' then 'White'
        when Pacific='No' then 'White'
        when Middle='No' then 'White'
        when Other='No' then 'White'
    end
When Hispanic='Yes' then
    case
        when Asian='No' then 'Hispanic'
        when Black='No' then 'Hispanic'
        when White='No' then 'Hispanic'
        when Pacific='No' then 'Hispanic'
        when Middle='No' then 'Hispanic'
        when Other='Yes' then 'Hispanic'
    end
When Pacific='Yes' then
    case
        when Asian='No' then 'Pacific'
        when Black='No' then 'Pacific'
        when White='No' then 'Pacific'
        when Hispanic='No' then 'Pacific'
        when Middle='No' then 'Pacific'
        when Other='No' then 'Pacific'
    end
When Middle='Yes' then
    case
        when Asian='No' then 'Middle'
        when Black='No' then 'Middle'
        when White='No' then 'Middle'
        when Hispanic='No' then 'Middle'
        when Pacific='No' then 'Middle'
        when Other='No' then 'Middle'
    end
When Other='Yes' then
    case
        when Asian='No' then 'Other'
        when Black='No' then 'Other'
        when White='No' then 'Other'
        when Hispanic='No' then 'Other'
        when Pacific='No' then 'Other'
        when Middle='No' then 'Other'
    end
else 'Multiple'
end AS Race
FROM Test;
```

Row 10 and 11 should be 'Multiple', (only Black is black OR black and other is black, only hispanic is hispanic OR hispanic and other is hispanic, except these two conditions if more than one 'yes' it will be 'Multiple'). Greatly appreciated your help or input . Thank You.

Comment: The `case` expression short-circuits, so after the first match nothing else will be evaluated. You probably should rethink your data model.

Comment: Structure normalization is strongly recommended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert your structure to

```sql
CREATE TABLE Test (
    id INT NOT NULL,
    Categories SET('Asian', 'Black', 'White', 'Hispanic', 'Pacific', 'Middle', 'Other') 
       NOT NULL CHECK (Categories <> '') );
```

And then

```sql
SELECT id, CASE WHEN BIT_COUNT(Categories) > 1
                THEN 'Multiple'
                ELSE Categories END AS Race
FROM Test;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f0cc3d82bf5761bfe23eb00d3c715769

Comment: Thank you. There is another problem with 'Multiple' and Other, if Black = Y and Other = Y it should be Black and Hispanic = Y and Other = Y it should be Hispanic, else more than one reported 'YES' is 'Multiple'.

Comment: @DBhatta https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=336772b5d20595e2faa9824f2a600511

Comment: It worked, Thank you Akina. So, first we can replace "Yes" to Asian in Asian column and No to NULL ... and so on for all columns in existing table (which i  have created) and can create 'Categories' column using CONCAT separated by ','.

Comment: I created a column "Categories" after  using CONCAT but BIT_COUNT didn't work, i mean i didn't get 'Multiple' and got rest of all. May be the because of variable type was Nvarchar (ALTER TABLE Test ADD Categories Nvarchar(255);)

Comment: @DBhatta Please look carefully. SET <> Nvarchar

Comment: ALTER TABLE Test
Add Race3 NVARCHAR (255) NOT NULL CHECK (Race2 <> '');
Update Test SET Race3 = 
    CONCAT_WS(',', Asian1, Black1, White1, Hispanic1, Pacific1, Middle1, Other1);  didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
IF (Other = 'Yes',
    ...,
    ...)
```

`Other` complicates things.  Perhaps it should be the first thing to test, splitting it into two lengthy case statements. One of them might be:

```
CASE
    WHEN LENGTH(CONCAT(Asian, Black, White, Hispanic, Pacific, Middle) != 13
                        THEN 'Multiple'
    WHEN Asian = 'Yes'  THEN 'Asian'
    WHEN Black = 'Yes'  THEN 'Black'
    ...
    END
```

Note: The `LENGTH` test must come first.

This is a kludge that assumes that "Yes" and "No" are the only possible values.  However, with `CHAR(..)`, there may be trailing spaces -- this would mess up the trick.  Can you switch to `VARCHAR(3)` or `ENUM('No', 'Yes')` ?

Other kludges could be used if the values were `1` and `0` or `"Asian"` and `NULL`; etc.

Comment: Thank you @Rick. After using this code I got rows 2 to 7 "Multiple", i changed VARCHAR to ENUM('No', 'Yes').

Comment: @DBhatta -- Oops, `=` should have been `!=`.

Comment: It worked but row 9 should be 'Black, 12 should be hispanic,  and 13 should be 'Black'. This is another condition when "Black and Other = Black" and "Hispanic and Other = Hispanic."

Comment: I added some thoughts on "Other".  Tomorrow, you will have another complication.  Good luck.

Comment: Now got 'Multiple'  and 'Other' gone. Yes, 'Other' makes complicated but i don't know how to execute first one code with splitting with second one.